# How to pass negative number as a command line argument in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a command line program that accepts two numbers as arguments, and I run it like this:

```
erl -noshell -s weight bmi 3 9
```

But I can't figure out how to process negative numbers. I've tried to pass them as strings, with `-extra` etc. It seems that Erlang, according to the documentation, interprets everything that starts with a hyphen as a flag:

> Any argument starting with character - (hyphen) is interpreted as a flag

So the question is: how to make Erlang consider, for example, `-10` as a number, not a flag?

```
erl -noshell -s weight bmi -10 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I can't figure it out how to process negative numbers(tried to
>   pass as strings, with -extra etc.

Here's an example of how to use the `-extra` flag:

```
-module(weight).
-compile(export_all).

bmi() ->
    [First|_Rest] = init:get_plain_arguments(),
    FirstAsInt = list_to_integer(First),
    io:format("~w~n", [FirstAsInt]),
    io:format("~w~n", [FirstAsInt + 1]).
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(weight).
```

At the command line:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl -noshell -s weight bmi -extra -9
-9
-8
```

Putting a negative number `before the first flag` or after `--` doesn't work for me.

If you try the following code, things might be clearer:

```
-module(weight).
-compile(export_all).

bmi() ->
    Args = init:get_plain_arguments(),
    io:format("~w~n", [Args]).
```

At the command line:

```
$ erl -noshell -s weight bmi -extra -9 abc
[[45,57],[97,98,99]]
```

`init:get_plain_arguments()` returns a list of arguments. The first arg is the list `[45,57]`, which can be created with the shorthand notation `"-9"`; and the second arg is the list `[97,98,99]`, which can be created with the shorthand notation `"abc"`.  Furthermore, a list/string can be converted to an integer with `list_to_integer()`.  The integer `45` is the ascii code for the hyphen character and the integer `57` is the ascii code for the character 9.  `list_to_integer()` is smart enough to handle negative signs.  Similarly, the integers `97,98,99` are the ascii codes for the characters `a,b,c`.

Answer (score 0):

The `-s` flag is for very simple API calls, such as `-s foo start` (calling `foo:start()`), and maybe passing a single argument as a mode flag or similar, like `-s foo start test` (calling `foo:start(test)`). The -s flag converts all arguments to atoms, so it's not suitable for passing integers. You can use the `-run` flag to do the same thing but passing arguments as strings, e.g. `-run foo start /tmp/` will call `foo:start("/tmp/")`, but to pass integers or other data types you have to parse the strings yourself.
The simplest and most flexible way is instead to use the `-eval` flag, like this:

```
erl -eval "foo:start(-1)"
```

Then you can execute any Erlang expression, and the system will parse the values for you. Make sure to use single quotes instead of double quotes in the shell command if you want to use special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a different character and translate it to `-`, e.g.

```
-module(sum).
-export([main/1]).

main([X,Y|_]) ->
    io:format("~B~n", [list_to_integer(maybe_negate(X))
                       + list_to_integer(maybe_negate(Y))]).

maybe_negate([First|Rest]) ->
    case First of
        $~ ->
            [$-|Rest];
        _AnyOther -> [First|Rest]
    end.
```

And invoking it:

```
$ erl -noshell -run sum main 3 ~5 -s init stop
-2
```